# Python name error: function is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

Description:

Define a function named map_squared_on_args(*args) which takes flexible integers and returns the a map object which is able to generate squared numbers among *args.

I typed this:

```
def map_squared_on_args(*args):   
  return list(map(lambda x:x**2, list(filter(lambda x: type(x)==int , args))))
```

And it shows:

```
NameError: name 'map_squared_on_args' is not defined
```

Please tell me how to fix that! Thanks a lot and apologize for the basic question.

Comment: Your definition of the function works for me. Have you executed the code where you define your function before calling it? Have you checked for typos between the function definition and calling of the function?

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible. Please considering adding more detail - including the line of code actually throwing this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Define the function
def map_squared_on_args(*args):   
  return list(map(lambda x:x**2, list(filter(lambda x: type(x)==int , args))))

#Call the function
map_squared_on_args(args)
```

Comment: you can improve your answer with some sample args to pass...